# Problem accessing object property created using Promise

Tags: javascript, class, promise

I am not able to access the returned object property, Please tell me why its returning undefined when data is object and giving correct value.

This is function created to sendHTTPRequest based on data.

```
import { countryCap } from "./capitalizingFunc.js";

export const sendHTTPRequest = (country) => {
  const capitalisedCountry = countryCap(country);
  return fetch(
    `https://covid-19-coronavirus-statistics.p.rapidapi.com/v1/total?country=${capitalisedCountry}`,
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "x-rapidapi-key": "3b0f2e00ebmsh95246403d9540c9p1506d4jsn3c44ce26f745",
        "x-rapidapi-host": "covid-19-coronavirus-statistics.p.rapidapi.com",
      },
    }
  )
    .then((response) => {
      const newResponce = response.json();
      return newResponce;
    })

    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
};
```

This is constructor class

```
export class casesDataFetcher {
  constructor(countryName) {
    sendHTTPRequest(countryName)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.data;
      })
      .then((data) => {
        this.country = data.location;
        this.cases = data.confirmed;
        this.recovered = data.recovered;
        this.deaths = data.deaths;
        console.log(this);
        return this;
      });
  }

}
```

This is execution function

```
import { casesDataFetcher } from "./casesDataFetcher.js";

export const screenDataShower = (country) => {
  const dataStorage = [];
  const globalInfected = document.querySelector(".infected h2");
  const globalActive = document.querySelector(".active h2");
  const globalDeaths = document.querySelector(".deaths h2");
  const globalRecovered = document.querySelector(".recovered h2");
  const globalCountries = document.querySelector(".countries h2");
  let promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    const recordedData = new casesDataFetcher(country);
    console.log(recordedData);
    resolve(recordedData);
  });
  return promise.then((data) => {
    console.log(typeof data);
    console.log(typeof data);
    console.log(data.cases); // NOT WORKING GIVING UNDEFINED
    globalInfected.textContent = `${nn.cases}`;
    globalActive.textContent = data.cases - data.recovered - data.deaths;
    globalDeaths.textContent = data.deaths;
    globalRecovered.textContent = data.recovered;
    globalCountries.textContent = 219;
  });
};
```

I also tried to convert the data to JSON again but still I was not able to access the property of returned data in screenDataShower

Comment: Don't mess with converting to JSON and the like unless you know what you're doing. The reason this doesn't work is that you're not waiting for the fetch promise to resolve.

Comment: Then how can it give the right data but not its property I am little confused can you please show me how its done

Comment: Here's one solution: https://jsfiddle.net/yxk47th5/

Answer (score 1):

you're calling sendHTTPRequest inside casesDataFetcher's constructor, from your code there's no guarantee data is resolved when you access it

extract sendHTTPRequest into a new function and wrap into a promise

```
export class casesDataFetcher {
  constructor(countryName) {
    this.countryName = countryName
  }
   
  fetch = () => {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      sendHTTPRequest(this.countryName)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.data;
      })
      .then((data) => {
        this.country = data.location;
        this.cases = data.confirmed;
        this.recovered = data.recovered;
        this.deaths = data.deaths;
        console.log(this);
        res(this);
      });
    })
  }
}
```

make screenDataShower function async then you can await data from fetch function in casesDataFetcher, this way it can guarantee data is there when you access it

```
import { casesDataFetcher } from "./casesDataFetcher.js";

export const screenDataShower = async (country) => {
  const dataStorage = [];
  const globalInfected = document.querySelector(".infected h2");
  const globalActive = document.querySelector(".active h2");
  const globalDeaths = document.querySelector(".deaths h2");
  const globalRecovered = document.querySelector(".recovered h2");
  const globalCountries = document.querySelector(".countries h2");

  const _casesDataFetcher = new casesDataFetcher(country)
  const data = await _casesDataFetcher.fetch()
   
  console.log(typeof data);
  console.log(typeof data);
  console.log(data.cases); // NOT WORKING GIVING UNDEFINED
  globalInfected.textContent = `${nn.cases}`;
  globalActive.textContent = data.cases - data.recovered - data.deaths;
  globalDeaths.textContent = data.deaths;
  globalRecovered.textContent = data.recovered;
  globalCountries.textContent = 219;
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked I was not binding setHTTPRequsest in a promise and wait for that promise to resolve after then I can try to access it

Comment: coungtd Can you please help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67342761/javascript-scrollable-calendar-position-and-logic-problem-minor-issues

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the json method of your response returns a promise instead of plain JSON. So you should change the call of the json method in your sendHTTPRequest function to something like:

```
.then((response) => {
  const newResponse = response.json().then((jsonResponse) => jsonResponse);
  return newResponse;
})
```

Comment: What is `.then((jsonResponse) => jsonResponse)` supposed to accomplish?